# JavaScript - Search object property by key and add its value to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
var object =  {
  "Defender": {
    "player-1868": {
      "birthdate": "1 July 1996",
      "club_country": "IQ",
      "club_id": 171,
      "club_name": "Erbil",
      "forename": "Burhan Jumaah",
      "id": 1868,
      "league_id": 12,
      "league_name": "Iraqi Premier League",
      "name": "Burhan Jumaah",
      "nationality": "iq",
      "nationality_full": "Iraq",
      "position": "Defender",
      "surname": "Razzaq",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Goalkeeper": {
    "player-3076": {
      "birthdate": "15 December 1985",
      "club_country": "QA",
      "club_id": 1,
      "club_name": "Lekhwiya",
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": "xxx",
          "name": "guy tester",
          "photoURL": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855450315704979460/RGiq07D7_normal.jpg",
          "time": 1496529030321,
          "user": "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
        }
      ],
      "forename": "Qasem Abdulhamed",
      "id": 3076,
      "league_id": 1,
      "league_name": "Qatar Stars League",
      "name": "Qasem Burhan",
      "nationality": "qa",
      "nationality_full": "Qatar",
      "position": "Goalkeeper",
      "surname": "Burhan",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    },
    "player-3532": {
      "birthdate": "2 April 1992",
      "club_country": "SA",
      "club_id": 18,
      "club_name": "Al Ittihad",
      "forename": "Fawaz",
      "id": 3532,
      "league_id": 2,
      "league_name": "Saudi Professional League",
      "name": "Fawaz Al Qarni",
      "nationality": "sa",
      "nationality_full": "Saudi Arabia",
      "position": "Goalkeeper",
      "surname": "Al Qarni",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

How would I, using `lodash`, traverse through this object and add every time the property `id` appears inside an object key of `player-xxxxxx`, add that value to an array. Essentially, getting all of the player IDs in a single `array`?

Comment: Is expected result `[1868, 3076, 3532]`? Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Comment: Can you change your title from `Javascript -` to `Lodash`? Makes it less deceptive towards your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Array#reduce` recursively on the object's keys to find the search string (player-), and create and extract the values:

```js
var object = {"Defender":{"player-1868":{"birthdate":"1 July 1996","club_country":"IQ","club_id":171,"club_name":"Erbil","forename":"Burhan Jumaah","id":1868,"league_id":12,"league_name":"Iraqi Premier League","name":"Burhan Jumaah","nationality":"iq","nationality_full":"Iraq","position":"Defender","surname":"Razzaq","votes":["y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"]}},"Goalkeeper":{"player-3076":{"birthdate":"15 December 1985","club_country":"QA","club_id":1,"club_name":"Lekhwiya","comments":[{"comment":"xxx","name":"guy tester","photoURL":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855450315704979460/RGiq07D7_normal.jpg","time":1496529030321,"user":"y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"}],"forename":"Qasem Abdulhamed","id":3076,"league_id":1,"league_name":"Qatar Stars League","name":"Qasem Burhan","nationality":"qa","nationality_full":"Qatar","position":"Goalkeeper","surname":"Burhan","votes":["y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"]},"player-3532":{"birthdate":"2 April 1992","club_country":"SA","club_id":18,"club_name":"Al Ittihad","forename":"Fawaz","id":3532,"league_id":2,"league_name":"Saudi Professional League","name":"Fawaz Al Qarni","nationality":"sa","nationality_full":"Saudi Arabia","position":"Goalkeeper","surname":"Al Qarni","votes":["y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"]}}};

function searchProps(searchStr, object) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(arr, key) { // reduce the objects keys to an array
    key.indexOf(searchStr) === -1 || arr.push(key.slice(searchStr.length)); // if a key contains the search string, take whatever after it
    
    var propValue = object[key];
  
    if(typeof propValue === 'object' && propValue !== null) { // if the value of the property is an array, run it through search props
      return arr.concat(searchProps(searchStr, propValue));
    }
    
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

var result = searchProps('player-', object);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, to traverse the keys and get each id, you may use "for" like below sample code:

```
var obj =  {
  "Defender": {
    "player-1868": {
      "birthdate": "1 July 1996",
      "club_country": "IQ",
      "club_id": 171,
      "club_name": "Erbil",
      "forename": "Burhan Jumaah",
      "id": 1868,
      "league_id": 12,
      "league_name": "Iraqi Premier League",
      "name": "Burhan Jumaah",
      "nationality": "iq",
      "nationality_full": "Iraq",
      "position": "Defender",
      "surname": "Razzaq",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Goalkeeper": {
    "player-3076": {
      "birthdate": "15 December 1985",
      "club_country": "QA",
      "club_id": 1,
      "club_name": "Lekhwiya",
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": "xxx",
          "name": "guy tester",
          "photoURL": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855450315704979460/RGiq07D7_normal.jpg",
          "time": 1496529030321,
          "user": "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
        }
      ],
      "forename": "Qasem Abdulhamed",
      "id": 3076,
      "league_id": 1,
      "league_name": "Qatar Stars League",
      "name": "Qasem Burhan",
      "nationality": "qa",
      "nationality_full": "Qatar",
      "position": "Goalkeeper",
      "surname": "Burhan",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    },
    "player-3532": {
      "birthdate": "2 April 1992",
      "club_country": "SA",
      "club_id": 18,
      "club_name": "Al Ittihad",
      "forename": "Fawaz",
      "id": 3532,
      "league_id": 2,
      "league_name": "Saudi Professional League",
      "name": "Fawaz Al Qarni",
      "nationality": "sa",
      "nationality_full": "Saudi Arabia",
      "position": "Goalkeeper",
      "surname": "Al Qarni",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    }
  }
};

var arr = [];
tgtObj = obj["Defender"];
for(var key in tgtObj){
    if (tgtObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log(key);
    arr.push(tgtObj[key]["id"]);
  }
}
tgtObj = obj["Goalkeeper"];
for(var key in tgtObj){
    if (tgtObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log(key);
    arr.push(tgtObj[key]["id"]);
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the object keys check to see if the string starts with "player-" and then push into an empty array the last four characters.

```js
var object = {
  "Defender": {
    "player-1868": {
      "birthdate": "1 July 1996",
      "club_country": "IQ",
      "club_id": 171,
      "club_name": "Erbil",
      "forename": "Burhan Jumaah",
      "id": 1868,
      "league_id": 12,
      "league_name": "Iraqi Premier League",
      "name": "Burhan Jumaah",
      "nationality": "iq",
      "nationality_full": "Iraq",
      "position": "Defender",
      "surname": "Razzaq",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Goalkeeper": {
    "player-3076": {
      "birthdate": "15 December 1985",
      "club_country": "QA",
      "club_id": 1,
      "club_name": "Lekhwiya",
      "comments": [{
        "comment": "xxx",
        "name": "guy tester",
        "photoURL": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/855450315704979460/RGiq07D7_normal.jpg",
        "time": 1496529030321,
        "user": "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      }],
      "forename": "Qasem Abdulhamed",
      "id": 3076,
      "league_id": 1,
      "league_name": "Qatar Stars League",
      "name": "Qasem Burhan",
      "nationality": "qa",
      "nationality_full": "Qatar",
      "position": "Goalkeeper",
      "surname": "Burhan",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    },
    "player-3532": {
      "birthdate": "2 April 1992",
      "club_country": "SA",
      "club_id": 18,
      "club_name": "Al Ittihad",
      "forename": "Fawaz",
      "id": 3532,
      "league_id": 2,
      "league_name": "Saudi Professional League",
      "name": "Fawaz Al Qarni",
      "nationality": "sa",
      "nationality_full": "Saudi Arabia",
      "position": "Goalkeeper",
      "surname": "Al Qarni",
      "votes": [
        "y884F42mLCVdld5V5cMeRpl11gJ2"
      ]
    }
  }
};

function getPlayers(object) {
  let items = [];
  for (let i in object) {
    let key = Object.keys(object[i]);
    key.forEach(i => i.startsWith('player') ? items.push(i.substring(i.length -4)) : '');
  }
  return items;
}
console.log(getPlayers(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself after some more time on it.

```js
var obj = {
  Defender: {
    "player-1868": {
      club_id: 171,
      id: 1868,
      league_id: 12,
      name: "Burhan Jumaah"
    }
  },
  Goalkeeper: {
    "player-3076": {
      club_id: 1,
      id: 3076,
      league_id: 1,
      name: "Qasem Burhan"
    },
    "player-3532": {
      club_id: 18,
      id: 3532,
      league_id: 2,
      name: "Fawaz Al Qarni"
    }
  }
};

function searchForProp(lookingFor, obj, arrYielded) {
  var arr = arrYielded ? arrYielded : [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, idx) {
    if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
  searchForProp(lookingFor, obj[key], arr);
 } else {
      if (key === 'id') {
    arr.push(obj[key]);
   }
    }
  });
 return arr;
}

var allIDs = searchForProp('id', obj);
console.log(allIDs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I could think of using lodash:

```
_(object).map(_.keys).flatten().value();
```

This of course assumes that the player keys are always at the same level in the object hierarchy.